# Wordpress - get_posts by tags and category

Tags: php, wordpress

The following is returning no results. I want to filter by category and multiple tags. Can you see what i am doing wrong?

```
$tags = array( "blah-blah", "sausage" );

$posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => $categoryID,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'tag'              => implode( ",", $tags )
) );
```

**EDIT**

**This seems to work!**:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => $categoryID,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'tag_slug__in'     => $tags
) );
```

Comment: `'tag_slug__in' => $tags` should work but it may not work with the category parameter.

Comment: @Popnoodles - Yep, all posts in category with tags. Yea, unfortuantely the above does not work.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with how WP builds the query. I would suggest trying `tag_slug__in` without `category` and then iterating through those results to filter just the required category.

Comment: @Popnoodles - It actually works. i was derping.

Comment: Which bit works so I can post an answer?

Comment: When querying across multiple taxonomies, I do prefer to use a `tax_query`. At ground level, tag and category queries are converted to a `tax_query` from which the SQL query is build :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category__and'         => $categoryID,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'tag__in'     => $tags
) );
```

Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

See below example to get posts by tags & category

```
global $wp_query;
        $args = array(
        'category__and' => 'category', 
        'tag__in' => 'post_tag', //must use tag id for this field
        'posts_per_page' => -1); //get all posts

$posts = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($posts as $post) :
  //do stuff 
     endforeach;
```